# What is meant by `local` while creating the oplog in pymongo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo

I want to tail a collection from a MongoDB. The official documentation (http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/tailable.html) has a line of code:

```
oplog = client.local.oplog.rs
first = oplog.find().sort('$natural', pymongo.ASCENDING).limit(-1).next()
```

What is meant by local in the above line of code?

I tried reading the official documentation and some SO answers but none explained anything.

Answer (score 0):

'local' is the database name where mongoDb creates the collection 'oplog.rs' for all replica-sets.
client.local.oplog.rs is equivalent to client.get_database('local').get_collection('oplog.rs')

Comment: So, if I want to connect to a remote mongodb and oplog it, what would be the case? `client = MongoClient(mongodb_host)` and then followed by `client.local` or `client.db_name`?

The catch is, mongodb_host contains database name as well.

Comment: Be it remote or locally hosted replica set, oplog is always saved in the database named 'local'. I understand your confusion with the name 'local' as it seems something related to your local machine. But it's not. 'local' is the name of the database used by MongoDB to save oplog. It has nothing to do with your system. So it has to be always client.local to access oplog.

Comment: but then i am facing error: `not allowed to operate on local`.

Comment: That seems like access issue. The user which you are using to connect to your mongo instance does not have access on 'local' database.